# how do I update fields with a select for the where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have tables, 1 called "articles" and another called "links".

I want to take the url and title from the table links and update the articles table with the data from the links table. I am unsure how to do this. The links table has article_id referenced to it, can anyone help?

Here is some pseudo-code if this helps?

```
UPDATE articles 
   SET articles.url, 
       articles.title = (SELECT links.url, 
                                links.title 
                           FROM links 
                          WHERE articles.id = links.article_id)
```

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE articles, links
SET articles.url = links.url,  
articles.title = links.title
WHERE articles.id = links.article_id
```

OR

```
UPDATE articles
INNER JOIN links ON (articles.id = links.article_id)
SET articles.url = links.url,  
articles.title = links.title
```

Comment: I always find it easier to explicitly specify a join & the condition, but this would work.

Comment: -1 for the kind of join used - this join technique leads to a lot of headaches. provide advice with Explicit Joins please.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: yes, I know it's a join, I know the current code works (I did not downvote), I just find it very much more legible seperating JOIN's ON's & WHERE's.

Comment: @Wrikken: No worries, preaching to the choir about ANSI-92 :)